# UITextField from NIB is not instantiated

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nib

I have to be missing something very obvious here...

I made a simple UIViewController with a corresponding nib.  In the nib, I added a label and a textfield.  I connected them to corresponding UILabel and UITextField objects on the view controller.  In viewDidLoad, the UILabel object is instantiated, but the UITextField is nil (0x0).  Is there some special action required to instantiate the UITextField?  I thought that all UI elements from a nib were automatically instantiated.

jorj

Comment: You sure you hooked your `UITextField` up to an `IBOutlet`?

Comment: Yes.  I've done it multiple times just to make sure.  I even deleted the textfield once and readded and reconnected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define an IBOutlet as an instance variable, make sure the corresponding @property has the same name or you will post a dumb question on stackoverflow and feel very stupid about it!

jorj